# Upload large file to shared onedrive folder with graph api (javascript)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm building a webapp that uploads pictures to onedrive  (buisness)
I can't seem to figure out how to upload a file to a shared folder shared with me. The below methode works fine for upload to my own folders, but are not able to upload to a shared folder.

```
async function uploadFile(file) {
    try {
        ensureScope('files.readwrite.all');
        let options = {
            path: uploadFolder,
            fileName: file.name,
            rangeSize: 1024 * 1024 // must be a multiple of 320 KiB
        };
        const uploadTask = await MicrosoftGraph.OneDriveLargeFileUploadTask
            .create(graphClient, file, options);
        const response = await uploadTask.upload();
        toast(`File ${file.name} of ${file.size} bytes uploaded`);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

I can browse the shared folders, so I know I get the path correct (/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/), but can't figure out how to upload to it? I also have write-access to the shared drive

It seems that it is possible with small files, but I haven't found any examples with the large file methode